# IndexRow variables in collection view cell does not change after reloadData()

Tags: swift, xcode

```
class SocialPlatformCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    //added cell
    @IBOutlet weak var btnDelete: UIButton!

    //variables
    var indexRow: Int = 0
    var parentCollectionView: UICollectionView?

    func setupIndex(_ indexRow: Int)
    {
        self.indexRow = indexRow
    }

    @IBAction func btnDeleteCell(_ sender: UIButton) {


        let UC = UserControllers()

        UC.deleteSocialPlatform(indexRow)
        {
            (socialplatformArray) in

            //use the linker to access to PatientInfoPersonalViewController elements
            ViewControllersLinkers.patientInfoVC?.userSocialPlatform = socialplatformArray

            let indexPath = self.parentCollectionView?.indexPath(for: self)
            self.parentCollectionView?.deleteItems(at: [indexPath!])

            print("this cell index is \(self.indexRow)")

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.parentCollectionView?.reloadData()
            }

        }

    }

}
```

this is the `collectionviewcell class` that i used for generating cell in collection view

```
class PatientPersonalInfoViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var cvSocialPlatform: UICollectionView!

    //the value for this array will be generated from the previous view controller using segue
    var userSocialPlatform: Array<String> = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //set delegate for collection view
        self.cvSocialPlatform.delegate = self
        self.cvSocialPlatform.dataSource = self

        //set the linker
        ViewControllersLinkers.patientInfoVC = self

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userSocialPlatform.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        var cell: SocialPlatformCollectionViewCell

        //if is first element of array
        if indexPath.row == 0
        {
            cell = cvSocialPlatform.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCell", for: indexPath) as! SocialPlatformCollectionViewCell

            cell.parentCollectionView = self.cvSocialPlatform
        }

        else
        {
            cell = cvSocialPlatform.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AddedCell", for: indexPath)as! SocialPlatformCollectionViewCell

            cell.setupIndex(indexPath.row)
            cell.parentCollectionView = self.cvSocialPlatform
        }

        return cell

    }
}
```

this is my `ViewCollection` class (user interface)

```
class UserControllers
{
    let dbManager = DatabaseManager()

    func deleteSocialPlatform(_ indexRow: Int, completion:@escaping(Array<String>) -> ())
    {
        let userRef = dbManager.databaseRef.child("users").child(dbManager.currentUserID!)

        userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        var socialplatformArray = value?["socialplatform"] as! Array<String>

        print("This cell index: \(indexRow)")
        socialplatformArray.remove(at: indexRow)
        let newValue = ["socialplatform": socialplatformArray]
        userRef.updateChildValues(newValue)
        completion(socialplatformArray)

        }

    }


}
```

this is my `UserControllers` that handle the deletion request when the user click on the delete button in the cell

However for some reason, whenever I delete a row, the index number of each cell would not change even after reloadData, but if i remove the `deleteItems(at:)` line, the index number do change and everything is fine. I want the animation of being deleted. I have no idea why does this happens. For instance, if I selected the second cell, the index number is 1 and then after it has been deleted, the third cell that move up will still have the index number of 2 instead of 1. This does not happen if I remove the `deleteItems(at:)` line

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be creating a new instance of UserControllers() when you call the following line.

let UC = UserControllers()

Instead, try passing the UC directly...

```
var userCont: UserControllers!

func setupIndex(_ indexRow: Int, _ userControllers: UserControllers) {
       self.indexRow = indexRow
       self.userCont = userControllers
}
```

Then in the delete function, call userCont.deleteSocialPlatform...

Otherwise, I would check out [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MC4mDQ7UqEE) which covers how to delete rows in a tableview efficiently.

Let me know if this worked?